# Solving gpg: decryption failed: No secret key

Tags: linux, debian, gpg, gpg-agent

I have encrypted a file through `gpg ***.gpg --encrypt --recipient ...@mail.com ***`

The hard disk with my Linux system where such file was encrypted has dead. I keep just the `***.gpg` file in an external hard drive.

When I try in my new Linux system `gpg --output *** --decrypt ***.gpg` I get

```
gpg: encrypted with RSA key, ID 7522CDC994071949
gpg: decryption failed: No secret key
```

Does this issue have a solution? I tried killing gpg-agent as suggested in some places, without success.

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: have you imported the private key?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`gpg` needs a private key to decypher your file. If you have none (because your disk is wiped), you won't be able to decipher it. In a sense, it is hopefully because on an other way other people would be able to decipher it too.

Then when using `gpg`, your `~/.gnupg` directory should be backuped with as many precaution as the enciphered files. You also have the `gpg --export > export` and  `gpg --export-secret-keys > export` commands to export all yours keys in a pair of files you should backup instead. But these precautions must be done before losing the disk.

`gpg-agent` is only a server which stores the keys in memory and make them available without typing the password twice. But this server needs the `~/.gnupg` files for reading your keys the first time you need them. (If it wouldn't, everybody could run this server and decipher your files).

The `gpg -K` prints the available secret keys. Then you can check your configuration.

Comment: Thanks! This are indeed quite bad news for me :(

Comment: `gpg --export` only saves the public keys, which is not enough; you need `gpg --export-secret-keys` (or a unique abbreviation) (which are indeed the ones shown by `gpg -K/--list-secret-keys`)